# Keras: TensorBoard Callback does not show training metrics

Tags: machine-learning, keras, visualization, tensorboard

I am trying to visualize loss and custom metrics in TensorBoard during training time using:

```python
visualizer = TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join(experiment_path, 'logs'), histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True,write_images=True,write_grads=False)

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
                     optimizer='adam',
                     metrics=[pearson_correlation,rmse,mean_true,mean_pred,kl_loss])


model.fit_generator(training_data_generator,
                           ....
                           callbacks=[lr_reducer, csv_logger, checkpoint, visualizer])
```

when I go start TensorBoard with: `tensorboard --logdir=...`

TensorBoard shows no scalars or images. Only the Graph is shown. I can see the metrics in the console as outputs. Is there a update frequency one should adjust? Or does Keras only show the metrics on the validation set?

Comment: No, this should be possible - I have used Tensorboard with Keras and both `loss` and `val_loss` are available in the Scalars tab; my only difference with your code is that I used `model.fit(x_train, y_train)` instead of using a training data generator...

Comment: How often does it update? Every epoch?

Comment: every epoch indeed

Comment: Did you set the verbose option in your fit_generator explicitly to 1 or 2? It's a default parameter, however,I think, it is worth a try.

Comment: To 1, somehow it gets stuck when set to 2

Comment: Ok noticed that it works after training for an epoch ...